# How to store time in protobuf 3

Tags: protobuf-3

I have this struct in golang

```
struct File {
  name string
  creatation_time time.Time
}
```

How do I write it in protobuf3 ?

Answer (score 4):

Create example.proto;

```
syntax = "proto3";

import google_protobuf "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp"

message File {
    string name = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp creatation_time = 2;  
}
```

After compilation check the example.pb.go for the structure definition that has been created.

Comment: which version of protoc are you using? I am is libprotoc 3.0.0, and I have to import "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.proto", also it gives me *google_protobuf.Timestamp not golang standard time.Time

Comment: `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";` worked for me